# How to convert stacked dataframe to dictionary in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have stacked dataframe as below. I tried to convert to the dictionary using `to_dict()` command. However, I got the following error.

```
TypeError: key ('PODIUM WINDOW', 'SHGC value') is not a string
```

Can anyone tell me what should I do further for this stacked dataframe to convert to the dictionary as below?

```
[{"Construction":"Office Window","U-value[W/m2-K]":1.63},{"Construction":"Office Window","SHGC value":0.22},{"Construction":"Podium Window","U-value[W/m2-K]":5.48},{"Construction":"Podium Window","SHGC value":0.70}]
```

**stacked dataframe**

```
Construction
OFFICE WINDOW  U-value[W/m2-K]    1.63
               SHGC value         0.22
PODIUM WINDOW  U-value[W/m2-K]    5.48
               SHGC value         0.70
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html), create column from `index` by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and last call [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.unstack().reset_index().to_dict(orient='records')
print (d)

[{'Construction': 'OFFICE WINDOW', 'SHGC value': 0.22, 'U-value[W/m2-K]': 1.63}, 
 {'Construction': 'PODIUM WINDOW', 'SHGC value': 0.7, 'U-value[W/m2-K]': 5.48}]
```

EDIT: Use list comprehension with `dictionary` by contructor:

```
d = [{'Construction': i, j:k} for (i, j), k in df.items()]
print (d)

[{'Construction': 'OFFICE WINDOW', 'U-value[W/m2-K]': 1.63}, 
 {'Construction': 'OFFICE WINDOW', 'SHGC value': 0.22}, 
 {'Construction': 'PODIUM WINDOW', 'U-value[W/m2-K]': 5.48}, 
 {'Construction': 'PODIUM WINDOW', 'SHGC value': 0.7}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I revised the dictionary format I want to get in question. Could you answer if possible?