# How I can incorporate comprehension with ordereddict in python?

Tags: python

I have created comprehension expression referring to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52734054/how-to-convert-stacked-dataframe-to-dictionary-in-pandas) converting stacked dataframe to specified dictionary format.

```
dict_data = [{'Construction': i, j: k} for (i, j), k in stacked.items()]
```

I tried to incorporate `OrderedDict` referring to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32895660/is-there-an-ordereddict-comprehension)
Changing to below.

```
dict_data = [OrderedDict(('Construction': i, j: k) for (i, j), k in stacked.items())]
```

but I get `invalid syntax error`
Could anyone tell me how should I fix this expression to incorporate with OrderedDict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to init the `OrderedDict` with tuples like:

```
dict_data = [OrderedDict((('Construction', i), (j, k))) for (i, j), k in stacked.items()]
```

Comment: I think you have a hanging bracket. I like to use lists to improve readability `[OrderedDict([('Construction', i), (j, k)]) for (i, j), k in stacked.items()]`

Comment: @Stephan Rauch Thank you! It worked! What about following case? 
dict_data = [{'Category': i, 'Type':j, k:l} for (i, j, k),l  in stacked.items()]

Comment: It is the same.  Instead of `{...}` use `OrderedDict(((..), (..)))` where each `..` is a key value pair.